# Show modal if not logged in

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a modal popup display allowing you to log in but only if you are not logged in.

I have tried many solutions but so far can only get the login to display in a new page.

Please see my code below

index.php

```
<?php 

require 'database_connection.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) {
    echo "<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show');</script>";
}

require 'includes/header.php';
?> 

***
***
if session type is 
set code goes here
***
***

<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Stock Code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label name="category_label" id="category_label">Category</label>
                                <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" required> 
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <?php echo fill_category_list($connect);?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Product Quantity</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" placeholder="Enter Qty" /> 
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="product_unit" id="product_unit" required disabled>
                                            <option value="Box">Boxes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Location</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_location" id="product_location" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                            <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

database_connection.php

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=continental3', 'root', 'password');
session_start();

?>
```

What am I missing?

On a side note if there is an easier or better way of doing this I'm happy to change my approach

Any help would be greatly appreciated

** UPDATE**

```
<?php

require 'database_connection.php'; //checks session type is set or not
require 'includes/header.php'; // Loads css and js files

if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) { //session check 


    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#loginModal").modal("show");});</script>'; 
} //open modal

require 'function.php'; 
require 'includes/navbar.php';

?>
```

The above code shows the modal as expected but only after the page has loaded. removing the document ready function the modal does not load but the rest of the page loads and displays (presumably because I do not use the else condition. When using the else condition as seen below nothing loads.

```
<?php

require 'database_connection.php';
require 'includes/header.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) { ?>


    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#loginModal").modal("show");});</script>';
 <?php } else {

require 'function.php'; 
require 'includes/navbar.php';

?>

***
***
if session type is 
set code goes here
***
***

<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Stock Code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label name="category_label" id="category_label">Category</label>
                                <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" required> 
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <?php echo fill_category_list($connect);?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Product Quantity</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" placeholder="Enter Qty" /> 
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="product_unit" id="product_unit" required disabled>
                                            <option value="Box">Boxes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Location</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_location" id="product_location" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                            <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } #close else ?>
```

Comment: You didn't start a session with `session_start();`

Comment: Sorry, @catcon I appreciate your answer, this is included in another file. I will amend my question to reflect this

Comment: Thanks for your input Emma, this made no difference though

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set $_SESSION['type'] ???

Please try this
index.php

```
<?php 

require 'database_connection.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) { ?>

   <script> $('#loginModal').modal('show'); </script>";

<?php } else {

require 'includes/header.php';
?> 

***
***
if session type is 
set code goes here
***
***

<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Stock Code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label name="category_label" id="category_label">Category</label>
                                <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control" required> 
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <?php echo fill_category_list($connect);?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Enter Product Quantity</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" placeholder="Enter Qty" /> 
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="product_unit" id="product_unit" required disabled>
                                            <option value="Box">Boxes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Location</label>
                                <input type="text" name="product_location" id="product_location" class="form-control" required disabled />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                            <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } #close else ?>
```

database_connection.php

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=continental3', 'root', 'password');
session_start();

?>
```

Comment: Still, no joy I am afraid Anandhukrishna VR.

$_SESSION['type'] is set in login.php which works if I would like to login on a new page but not a modal window.

You can visit login.php which will set the session type and all works fine using

```if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) {
    header("location:login.php");
}```

Comment: So.. actually what your problem?

Comment: At the moment the code in my previous comment that works redirects to login.php page. I am trying to get a modal to show if session type is not set instead of redirect to the login page

Comment: replscr redirection code to if (!isset($_SESSION["type"])) { //model code }